# How to use getenv() in php and SetEnv in a .htaccess with a compiled php-cgi on a shared host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, shared-hosting

Just putting in context to clarify the main question:

On my development machine, PHP5.3.1 is installed on Apache as a module, I use SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT development in my application's root .htaccess file. It is then easily retrievable from any php script with getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT').

On the production server, on a sharedhost (dreamhost), I compiled myself php5.3.1 since it was not directly supported. Everything works fine except that getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') returns false.

In the sharedhost root .htaccess for my domain, I use this .htaccess file

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler php-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php.cgi

<FilesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</FilesMatch>

Options -indexes
```

php5.cgi resides in /cgi-bin and works very well.
Of course in my application's root folder I have another .htaccess defining:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT production
```

But when using getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') it returns false, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe your host does not allow this directive to be overridden in .htaccess files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok I finally got it. On dreamhost, it is possible to use fastcgi and therefore declare environment variables with it. It consists of just adding this simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2
exec /home/USERNAME/YOURDOMAIN/cgi-bin/php.cgi
```

Which is where my compiled PHP5.3.1 was located.
chmod 744 on that file called dispatch.fcgi which will be allowed more memory by dreamhost's watchdog.

After that I added to my domain's .htaccess the following:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fastcgi-script fcg fcgi fpl
AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
Action php5-fastcgi /dispatch.fcgi
```

now in the application's root I have another .htaccess with:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT staging
```

In a php script is is retrievable via getenv('REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT');

Comment: oh thank you!!! I was losing hair trying to set an environment variable in .htaccess. I was able to finally do it by changing PHP from running as a CGI application to FastCGI.

Comment: Why are you using getenv('REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') instead of getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') ?

Comment: For this to work for me, I had to leave off the prepended "REDIRECT_" part of the environment variable.

Comment: +1 Had an issue with Magento 1.5 setting environment variables with SetEnvIf Host. The variables MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE were being set in the PHP super global $_SERVER as REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE and REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE. This answer got me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

For the [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive to work, your hosting service must have the `mod_env` module activated...

But, even if it's activated, maybe you don't have to permission to use [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv).

Just to be sure the problem is not in your code, you might want to check the ouput of [`phpinfo()`](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) : at the bottom of the page, there should be a section containing environment variables as seen from PHP -- if yours is not in there, it's not a good sign for you...

Comment: Yep you are right, I am not finding anything under PHP variables under the production server and I do on my development machine. I am contacting their support for this and will try to provide a workaround answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order for $_ENV to work, I had to reconfigure `variables_order = "GPCSE"` in php.ini. By default, it did not include E for $_ENV, it was originally `variables_order = "GPCS"`

> This directive determines which super global arrays are registered when PHP starts up. G,P,C,E & S are abbreviations for the following respective super
>   globals: GET, POST, COOKIE, ENV and SERVER. There is a performance penalty
>   paid for the registration of these arrays and because ENV is not as commonly
>   used as the others, ENV is not recommended on productions servers. You
>   can still get access to the environment variables through getenv() should you
>   need to.
>
> Default Value: "EGPCS"
>
> Development Value: "GPCS"
>
> Production Value: "GPCS";
>
> http://php.net/variables-order