# How to test kohana model, controller

Tags: tdd, phpunit, kohana, kohana-3

I have been working with php for more than 5 years. Lately I have worked in rubyonrails. I have done a few projects in this very nice framework. What I like best from rails and ruby: they both promote automate test and there are so many rich libs. Rspec and TestUnit are very easy to learn comparing to PhpUnit.

I have to develop a very big project in the next coming month. I am a big fan in cakephp but I realize that cakephp will not meet my project requirement. I am a quick learner. After reading doc from Kohana official website, I will use Kohana for this project.

After having done some search on Kohana, I still have a few topics to concern about

1. The test module is lack of doc. I am not clear how to test model, controller, functional test. Could anyone provide me ideas, tutorials, examples, resources ?
2. The application environment is not quite clear. Sorry because I am pretty family with rubyonrails . I feel like environment in rails make more sense to me. I can have one gem in a specific environment. for example I have rspec gem (for automate test ) for test environment only and I have unicorn gem for production only. For those who are new to ruby, gem is something similar to "module" in kohana. Could anyone tell me how to tell kohana to just load "unittest" in test environment only ? because I don't want to load unittest in production env.
3. In Rails there is an app console mode called rails console. with rails console we can interact with models via console mode . Is there anything similar to this in Kohana ?

Comment: Brandons proposed a very nice solution for the second question http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/68904?post#Form_Body

Answer (score 3):

I can answer only 2 of your questions, still better then nothing ;)

**AD2**. You can set `Kohana::$environment` variable based on the .htaccess (`setenv` and `getenv`) / `$_SERVER` setting:

```
if (Arr::get($_SERVER, 'SERVER_NAME') !== 'localhost')
{
    // We are live!
    Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;

    // Turn off notices and strict errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT);
}
else
{
    Kohana::$environment = Kohana::DEVELOPMENT;
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
}
```

Then you can setup `Kohana::init` like this:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url' => '/',
    'caching' => Kohana::$environment === Kohana::PRODUCTION,
    'profile' => Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION,
    'index_file' => FALSE,
    'errors' => TRUE
));
```

so your production application will have caching enabled and profiling disabled.
For the modules it's pretty much the same:

```
if (Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION)
{
    Kohana::modules(array(
        'unittest' => MODPATH . 'unittest',
    ));
}
```

**AD3**. Sorry for being laconic - no, there isn't one.

Comment: I have configure virtual host to use full qualified domain name. for example www.niph.com.kh. I might also want to run  localhost in production mode. So I think by checking server name name is not a good approach for me  . Do you have any other approaches ?

Comment: Then you could use setenv and getenv - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008123/how-to-use-getenv-in-php-and-setenv-in-a-htaccess-with-a-compiled-php-cgi-on