# PHP/Server Side: How to properly conceal database credentials files

Tags: php, web-hosting, document-root

I've had lots of problems concealing database credentials needed for PHP classes. None of the "solutions" recommended worked so far.

1) PHP manual recommends to save the credentials in a different file: check!
All my PHP database classes insert the credentials from a different file.

**Typical db class**

```
class database{
private static $dbc = null;

public static function get($page,$component = null){
    if(self::$dbc === null) {
        $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path = '/some path/';
        $file = 'pdo.php';
        require( $root . $path . $file );
    }
 ...more code...
```

**credentials file**

```
$dbhost = 'some.host';
$dbname = 'someDBname';
$dbuser = 'someUser';
$dbpass = 'somePassword';
```

2) Despite this, the file where I keep all the info in the web-host, the file can be sniffed or found.

**How can I conceal this file, containing the database info, in order to have a REALLY secure website and database?**

Comment: *"the file can be sniffed or found"* – by whom and how?

Comment: Ultimately, the credentials *have* to be accessible to the server's PHP processes. Host on non-shared hosting (VPS, dedicated server, etc.) on a major provider you trust.

Comment: We don't know what the `recommended solutions` you've read are. Can you add what you've tried? I'd move the file outside a web accessible directory.

Comment: And the answer is simply: don't put the file into your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`! In fact, you should put *most* of your PHP files outside the document root.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend putting them in environment variables. You can [`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getenv.php)

And you can set them through either a `.env` (Symfony and Laravel are both using this: [Example](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example)) file, or in a `.htaccess` file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008123/how-to-use-getenv-in-php-and-setenv-in-a-htaccess-with-a-compiled-php-cgi-on).

Bonus: If you're paranoid, you can throw in a salt and use a hashed password, as explained [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354242/a-better-approach-than-storing-mysql-password-in-plain-text-in-config-file) but I doubt that this changes much.

---

Edit: In the comments it was suggestion by @deceze not to store the credentials file in the document root. That's definitely something you should follow.

Let me elaborate. Let's say your domain example.com points to `www/foo/bar/example.com/` don't store the file in there like `www/foo/bar/example.com/db.php` but store it a level up at `www/foo/bar/db.php` that way it can't be accessed through the browser, but PHP can still access ist, through `include` or `require`. You can add `..` to a path to go one folder back. If you have it sitting in the document root, it could be accessed using http://example.com/db.php and if your server isn't configured properly (or you use another formal like `db.yml` or something), it could serve the file and thus expose your credentials
Note: The `db.php` file is just an example. As stated above, I'd strongly recommend using environment variables!

---

Edit 2:
To stick with your example and a PHP solution without using environment variables. You could use something like this:

```
// the db class
class database{
    private static $dbc = null;

    public static function get($page,$component = null){
        if(self::$dbc === null) {
            $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $path = '/../db/';
            $file = 'pdo.php';
            require( $root . $path . $file );

            self::$dbc = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPass);
        }

        return self::$dbc;
    }
}

// the pdo.php file
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$dbUser = 'dbuser';
$dbPass = 'dbpass';
```

The file structure would be something like

```
www
  foo
    yourwebsite
      .htaccess
      index.php
      foobar.php
    db
      pdo.php
```

The website example.com would point to `www/foo/yourwebsite`